# Questions about CSS bundling in Rails 7

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

Rails 7. New App with Bootstrap CSS, JS Bundling, and CSS Bundling. This results in structure of:

```
app/assets/builds, 
app/images/foo.jpg, 
app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss
```

and using Yarn to add Bootstrap to package.json, with ESBuild for JS build and Sass for CSS build.

It all works until I try add a simple CSS class to the application.bootstrap.scss sass file:

```
.bg {
  background-image: url("foo.com");
}
```

What I really want here, is the asset in app/assets/images/foo.jpg to be referenced properly. It is a scss file, so sass. When I use the sass commands:

```
background-image: image-url("foo.com");
```

or

```
background-image: url(image-path("foo.com"));
```

nothing works in development, or production, so that my application.css build file is correct. I get errors about syntax ending in a "we found a .jpg but should be (1px 0 solid) or something like that. In other words, the sass compile is not making a valid css build.

What am I supposed to be doing here to make a simple class with an image asset be part of my delivered application.css bundle? Should I be creating a separate css file and adding that to the sprockets manifest? Seems like overkill.

At the moment the only thing that worked was just adding an inline style to my ERB layout, which is totally bogus bad, but all I could do to just move on.

As an extra question, which I know I should not ask here, I also want to reference an image I add to the Rails App, so that https://myapp.com/my-image.png is just available. I used to park this in /public/my-image.png but if I wanted to instead use /app/assets/images/my-image.jpg what would my link be? I guess it would be all fingerprinted and not accessible, but perhaps I am wrong. Is there any point to referencing an asset instead of parking it in /public or am I forced to use /public?

Answer (score 0):

see
https://github.com/rails/cssbundling-rails/issues/102

did you try

.test {
background-image: url("foo.jpg");
}

https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails#initializer-options

config.assets.resolve_assets_in_css_urls

When this option is enabled, sprockets-rails will register a CSS postprocessor to resolve assets referenced in [url()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url()) function calls and replace them with the digested paths. Defaults to true.